# How to call a function or sub inside a VB.NET DLL from a VB.NET WinForms Code?

Tags: .net, vb.net, winforms, dll

I searched like crazy before I posted this; I could not find a clear explanation for what I'm trying to do, although it seems trivial for those who have done it before.

I have a VB.NET WinForms project, and I want to put my functions and subs inside a DLL to facilitate their maintenance.

The DLL was created using a VB.NET Class and is being compiled without issues.

When I reference the DLL in the WinForms project, though, I'm not being able to call any function or sub inside the DLL. My WinForms project can see the namespaces inside the DLL, but I cannot get beyond that.

Did I watch a video on YT but could not trace a parallel to my case.

In this particular example in the image, I was expecting to use something like this in my WinForms project to, for example, call the sub "KillAProcess" declared inside the DLL.

```
MFGSystems.Common.Resources.KillAProcess("Explorer")
```

This is what I'm seeing, though:

The DLL:

[image]

The WinForms project:

[image]

What am I doing wrong?

Tks!

Comment: Firstly, don't post code as only pictures. Add a picture if it adds value but ALWAYS post your code as text, formatted as code.

Comment: `Resources` is a bad name for that class for multiple reasons. Firstly, projects already use that name for actual resources, so you're setting things up for a name clash. Secondly, types should be named descriptively, so those classes should group members with related functionality and then the names should reflect that group functionality.

Comment: It's not a bad idea to get familiar with how to create DLLs but it's not something you should do just for the hell; of it. For small projects and where the functionality will not be used in any other project, you really ought to keep all the functionality in the one project. That project can contain as many types as you like.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You appear to be trying to call your method directly on the class, rather than an instance of the class. You need to create an instance of the `Resources` class and call your method on that object. You do this all the time so I'm not sure why it's a mystery here. If you don't want to have to create that object then either declare the method `Shared` or else make the type a module rather than a class.